# Create the on-topic (page) for this community

Tags: discussion, status-completed, scope

In the help center of Hinduism.SE, the [on-topic](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section is empty / has nothing site-specific.

For example, in other religious sites like [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) have it properly updated. Even recent public beta sites like [Health](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [Music Fans](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) have a proper on-topic section.

I think we can also use this space to specify what is allowed here and what is not allowed (e.g., scientific questions).

Comment: Well, here are some on-topic things: questions about Hindu scripture; questions about Hindu mythology; academic questions about Hindu philosophical thought; questions about Hindu practices; historical questions about the evolution of Hinduism; questions about different sects of Hinduism and their beliefs.  And here are some off-topic things: personal advice questions; scientific speculation; questions about which sect or school of Hindu thought is correct; questions soliciting opinion.

Comment: @AnkitSharma add the [faq-proposed] tag. (You know much better about how it works than me) (cc @Keshav)

Comment: @BhargavRao Its one of my agendas and i will surely take it forward just waiting for [resolution here first](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/441/change-the-moderators-of-hinduism-se-site?cb=1).  [tag:faq-proposed]  tag doesn't sound good to me and i don't thing it need [tag:faq] tag either, just need to copy it to our  off-topic section by mod.

Comment: @BhargavRao [This one](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/207/define-off-topic-close-reasons) also is of same importance to me. It will give appropriate close reason for user.

Comment: Nice. Hopefully we see the site bubbling with activity soon.

Comment: @BhargavRao I blame my own-self for it too, i didn't given this site much time lately either, That's why i am picking on all those metas again from my radar ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**What topics can I ask about here?**

**Hinduism Stack Exchange** is for followers of the Hindu religion and those interested in learning more about Hinduism.

You've come to the right place if you have questions about:

> - [Hindu](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/75/2995) scripture and [mythology](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2799/2995).
> - Academic questions about Hindu philosophical thought.
> - Questions about Hindu practices.
> - Historical questions about the evolution of Hinduism.
> - Different sects of Hinduism and their beliefs.

Please note that the following subjects are considered off-topic here:

> - Personal advice questions.
> - Scientific speculation.
> - Questions soliciting opinion.

---

Above is my take on the page from the Idea taken from  Keshav's comment and Christianity.SE for general idea. It's community wiki so anyone can edit it to make it more accurate.

Comment: Adding examples of on-topic and off-topic questions would help.

Comment: Its community wiki, you can add your input easily by edit.

Comment: **Note:** It has been made live now but don't forget-  "nothing is permanent", so if you still have some suggestions feel free to ask them, new improvements can be implement if got enough support.

Comment: Looks good! I would add a link to this [question](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2797/2995) or [@Sai's answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2799/2995) for the word 'mythology' used in [the first bullet](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I would also add a link to the word 'Hindu' in the first bullet. Link it to this question: [What is the origin of the word “Hindu”?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/65/2995)

Comment: @sv. I don't feel it that necessary

Answer (score -1):

Wikipedia has very helpful template on [Hinduism Topics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Hindudharma):

[image: screen-shot]

I am here posting the proposed [on-topic](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for the [site](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/). If you have any suggestion for improvement then comment or post a better answer.

---

**What topics can I ask about Here?**

> Hinduism Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for followers of the Hindu religion and those interested in learning more about Hinduism.
>
> If your question is about:
>
> - Hinduism concept, thoughts, believes & schools of [philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_philosophy).
> - Hindu texts/scriptures, mythology & deities
> - Hindu practices (worship, yoga etc.), rites & rituals.
> - History of Hinduism - periods and evolution
> - Different denominations, traditions or religious systems and their beliefs
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!
>
> Note that For the other religions/cultures, see [Buddhism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/), [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/), [Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/) or refer to [site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Personally I like Ankit's phrasing better.